# Do all the lists of a non referenced list of lists get deleted by garbage collector?

Tags: python

I have:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
```

I want to reuse `a` and empty it. Is it correct to do `a=list()` or I need to go manually into each list and empty it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a = list()` or `a = []` will create a new list object. If you *actually* want to empty the list, `a[:] = []` or `del a[:]` will do that. If you print `id(a)` before and after each operation you'll see the difference.

There's no need to empty out the sublists. If there are no references remaining they'll be garbage collected.

Comment: Thank you. Are there advantages/disadvantages between the two methods?

Comment: It mainly matters if you have other references to the list. If you create a new list those references will be unaffected; if you empty the list in place, they will.